# Specifying the version of bundle

Tags: docker, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I am building a website using bundle and im building it through docker containers. Apparently when i install ruby-bundler, its giving me bundler 1.15.1 instead of 1.16.4 and it throws a warning that my bundler is outdated. This is leading to some other issues with some files im trying to update.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
gcc \
make \
ruby \
ruby-dev \
locales \
ruby-bundler \
zlib1g-dev \
curl
RUN gem install bundler 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add support for UTF-8.
RUN localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
```

The line  `RUN gem install bundler` is fixing the issue for me locally, but not on the docker image. So I ran `which -a bundle` and it gave me two directories: `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. The new bundler seems to be installed on the `local/bin` and when i run `bundle install` it doesnt look for the `local/bin` therefore it throws me the warning.

What would be the best way to overcome this? Just keep in mind it has to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want only the newest version provided by `gem install bundler`

In that case all you need is to remove the `ruby-bundler` from the apt-get install remaining with this final Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
gcc \
make \
ruby \
ruby-dev \
locales \
zlib1g-dev \
curl
RUN gem install bundler 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add support for UTF-8.
RUN localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
```